# How does file upload works in ZF2?

Tags: file-upload, zend-framework2

How does it send the file internally? 
I just would like to know how it handle the file when uploading.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite vague. A lot depends on the context.

in the context of form check this links:

- http://framework.zend.com//2.3/en/modules/zend.form.file-upload.html
- http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/08/31/zend-framework-2-creating-upload-form-file-validation/

Comment: I did the http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/08/31/zend-framework-2-creating-upload-form-file-validation/ module, it works for me.but i want to do like image resizing,for that i want to handle the file.I don't know to handle that thing.

Comment: hi, after uploading the image file, you can use external library to resize the uploaded image. http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/projects/timthumb/ would do the good job. You need to pass your uploaded image absolute path as URL_PATH_TO_timthumb.php?src=UPLOADED_IMAGE_PATH